# print mismatch items in two array

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I want to compare two array(4 floating point)and print mismatched items.
I used this code:

```
>>> from numpy.testing import assert_allclose as np_assert_allclose
>>> x=np.array([1,2,3])
>>> y=np.array([1,0,3])
>>> np_assert_allclose(x,y, rtol=1e-4)

AssertionError: 
Not equal to tolerance rtol=0.0001, atol=0

(mismatch 33.33333333333333%)
 x: array([1, 2, 3])
 y: array([1, 0, 3])
```

the problem by this code is with big array:

```
(mismatch 0.0015104228617559556%)
 x: array([ 0.440088,  0.35994 ,  0.308225, ...,  0.199546,  0.226758,  0.2312  ])
 y: array([ 0.44009,  0.35994,  0.30822, ...,  0.19955,  0.22676,  0.2312 ])
```

I can not find what values are mismatched. how can see them ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just use

```
~np.isclose(x, y, rtol=1e-4)  # array([False,  True, False], dtype=bool)
```

e.g.

```
d = ~np.isclose(x, y, rtol=1e-4)
print(x[d])  # [2]
print(y[d])  # [0]
```

or, to get the indices

```
np.where(d)  # (array([1]),)
```

Comment: this dos not work for floating number: >>> import numpy as np
>>> x=np.array([1.123456,2,3])
>>> y=np.array([1.1234,  0,3])
>>> ~np.isclose(x, y)
array([ True,  True, False], dtype=bool)

Comment: this says that 1.1234 and 1.123456 are not same. I want to calculate comparison by  4 floating point. then these items are equal.

Comment: It says they are *not the same*. And why don't you just set your custom `rtol` argument?